# Getting Error LNK1168 and then its stop debugging

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, mfc

I'm new to VC++ ( mfc ) application development. And usually getting `LNK1168`error and after that program stop working. only solution works for me is that i have to close the application(Visual Studio 2010) and reopen it.

Is it possible that i'm making mistakes in my code and I m not able to make application flawless or my machine is malfunctioning?
Question is too dumb but i'm sorry for that.

Googled about this problem and tried many solution but did not work for me at all, except i've mentioned earlier.

Any help would be appreciable.I got mad about this problem. :(

I've tried to launch my project in Release mode too, but it will asking me to restart the VS2010.
Not working for me at all, and my partners are not getting this error at all.I've run my application on their PCs and its not getting that error on their PCs. What to do?

**Solutions I've tried.**

1. Disable the Microsoft Security Essential.
2. Right click on project -> property -> linker -> input -> additional dependencies add dll files path.
3. Open command prompt and kill the process by the command `TASKKILL /F /IM Program1.exe`
4. Last which works for me. Close the VS2010 and open it again.

Comment: [LNK1168](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hhbdtt6d.aspx) means: *"cannot open filename for writing"*. This happens occasionally with Visual Studio and/or certain anti-malware software, that keep the binary file open for longer than necessary, which prevents the linker from writing to it. What anti-malware software are you using (if any)?

Comment: @IInspectable Microsoft Security Essential.

Comment: `usually getting LNK1168error and after that program stop working` You'll need to be more specific. After a link error, there is no `program` being newly built, so it's not clear what did `stop working` for you afterwards. If, per your last edit, it works again after restarting VS2010 then you may have some case of a previous debugging session left hanging, but that's just a guess.